# Rebus Overload!

Tags: rebus

Here are a few one-liner rebus puzzles for you to solve.

1. T_ _ E
2. O _ E R _ T _ O _
3. swear
   bible
   bible
   bible
   bible
4. hoppin
5. injury + insult
6. COLT jr.
7. cut
   cut cut cut cut
   cut cut cut cut
8. GIFIREN
9. VA DERS
10. ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
11. WINEEEEEE
12. SOMething
13. END
     N
     D
14. April 5
     April 5
15. LIPS     LIPS

Comment: Nice collection!  I'm actually using some of these in a childrens' magazine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### [Community wiki]: The results of a collaboration by Len and Gamow:

Number 1:

> T_ _ E = IM taken out of TIME = **I'm out of time**

Number 2:

> O _ E R _ T _ O _ = OPERATION without PAIN = **painless operation**

Number 3:

> **Swear on a stack of bibles**

Number 4:

> hoppin = center part of SHOPPING = **Shopping center**

Number 5:

> injury + insult = **To add insult to injury**

Number 6:

> COLT jr. = **young gun**

Number 7:

> **a cut above the rest**

Number 8:

> GIFIREN = FIRE in GIN = **fire engine**

Number 9:

> VA DERS = space in VADERS = **space invaders**

Number 10:

> ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ = **Long time no see**

Number 11:

> WINEEEEEE = WIN with Es = **to win with ease**

Number 12:

> SOMething = **the start of something big**

Number 13:

> **to make ends meet**

Number 14:

> **double date**

Number 15:

> LIPS LIPS = two lips = **tulips**